# Confusion with math.round()

Tags: java

Here is some code with which I'm confused :

```
public class MathOpration {  
   public static void main(String args[])  
   {  
       float F1 = -5.5f;   
float F2 = 5.5f;   
float F3 = -5.49f;   
float F4 = 5.49f;   
System.out.println("Round F1 is " + Math.round(F1));   
System.out.println("Round F2 is " + Math.round(F2));   
System.out.println("Round F3 is " + Math.round(F3));   
System.out.println("Round F4 is " + Math.round(F4));   

   }  
}
```

The out come of the above is :

```
Round F1 is -5
Round F2 is 6
Round F3 is -5
Round F4 is 5
```

My confusion is how -5 became the output for F1?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: .5s round up.  Rounding up from -5.5 is -5, and rounding up from 5.5 is 6.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the documentation for [`round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)):

> In other words, the result is equal to the value of the expression:
>
> ```
> (int)Math.floor(a + 0.5f)
> ```

This explains why `-5.5f` rounds to -5, but `5.5f` rounds to 6. ([`floor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) gives "Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is not greater than the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.".)

Answer (score 2):

```
-6 is less than -5
```

And when you round up, you go up.

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is how -5 became the output for F1?

.5 is allways rounded UP.

Since -5.5 is negative, it's rounding UP to -5.

Answer (score 0):

You can round however you want if the results are not what you desire.  Check out this little explanation of rounding.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128174000/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71202.html)

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent which is sometimes faster is

```
long l = (long) (f + 0.5);
```